# Recovering nat from a positive integer in Lean

Tags: lean

Given `(a : Z)` and `(a >= 0)`, I would like to have `(n : N)` such that `n = a`. This is of course a bit troublesome because `n = a` is heterogeneous equality.

I have found `nat_abs` which does something like this except it also handles the case when I have a negative whole number, which I know that I don't.

How does one deal with this situation in Lean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n = a` isn't a heterogeneous equality, since you (hopefully) can't prove `N = Z`. The best you can hope for is `int.of_nat n = a`, and you should be able to prove from `a >= 0` that `int.of_nat (nat_abs a) = a`.

Note that you can *write* `a = n`, and it will type check, because Lean will coerce `n` to `int.of_nat n`. This is not a heterogeneous equality, it's a normal equality in `Z`.

Comment: Right, this may have been a bit of a misnomer used by me, I just meant that `n = a` would require equality between elements of different types. As you've pointed out, `0 <= a` implies `coerce (nat_abs a) = a`.